# How to unmount Google Bucket in Linux created with gcsfuse

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, gcsfuse

I have mapped Google Storage `bucket` as ubuntu drive with:

```
gcsfuse googlebucketname  /home/shared/local_folder/
```

How to reverse the previous step by unmounting `/home/shared/local_folder/` from the linked `bucket`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's belong to http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/a8d9f02/docs/mounting.md#unmounting), you want:

```
fusermount -u /home/shared/local_folder/
```

Comment: The regular umount command should work as well: `sudo umount /mnt/gcs-bucket`